# A join condition must be specified, getting this error peewee python.

Tags: python, mysql, orm, mysql-python, peewee

I'm trying to join 2 tables to view their contents.

```
Users.select().join(User_profiles).where(Users.users_id == User_profiles.users_id)
```

My **Users Model**:

```
class Users(Model):
    users_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    mobile_number = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        database = db_connection()
```

My **User_profiles Model**:

```
class User_profiles(Model):
    users_id = IntegerField()
    user_profiles_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    profile_name =  CharField()
    address = CharField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField()    

    class Meta:
        database = db_connection()
```

I have specified "users_id" from "Users Model" as the Foreign Key for "User_profiles Model". How to specify the join condition the right way? I had read the peewee doc and did Google Search but nothing helped. Can someone help me with the code?

Comment: i think `user_profiles_id` should be written as `user_profiles_id = ForeignKeyField(Users)`